# ROW_NUMBER count returns invalid result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am quite new to SQL Server and trying to improve myself. I prepared a statement for fetching customers that are cancelled (where customerCancel is true)

Normally, when I count total number of cancelled customers, the total number is 1050.

What I want to do is to show first 100 users, but when I run the query below, I only get 38, when I increase RowNumber manually, the result is increasing but not being same with actual result. I will use this query for pagination.

My query:

```
SELECT
   COUNT(*) OVER() TotalRowCount,
   ID, customerNo, customerName, customerSurname, customerTitle, customerUnitList, customerTotalList 
FROM
   (SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY m.ID) RowNumber, 
        COUNT(*) OVER() TotalRowCount,
        m.ID, m.customerNo, m.customerName, m.customerSurname, m.customerTitle,
        (SELECT COUNT(f.ID) 
         FROM Invoices f 
         WHERE f.Paid = 0 
           AND f.custumerCancel = 0 
           AND f.customerID = m.ID) AS customerUnitList,
        COALESCE((SELECT SUM(f.Total) AS InvoiceNo
                  FROM Invoices f 
                  WHERE f.Paid = 0 
                    AND f.custumerCancel = 0 
                    AND f.customerID = m.ID), 0) AS customerTotalList 
    FROM
        Customers m) flist 
WHERE
   customerTotalList > 0 
   AND RowNumber between 1 AND 100
```

I tried several way to fix it but no luck.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. (Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before you start.)

Comment: Maybe try replacing `ROW_NUMBER() OVER ...` by `DENSE_RANK() OVER ...`

That will put the same rownumber to all records with the same id

Comment: @jarlh I am on it, thanks. @user10600584, tried `DENSE_RANK()` aswell but same output :(

Comment: and have you checked what output you get with rownumber in your `SELECT` list? Just in case the condition `customerTotalList>0` is getting in the way. I will wait for sample data too, if that is not the solution either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT * FROM   (SELECT Count(*) OVER()   TotalRowCount, 
               Row_number() 
                 OVER(ORDER BY id) RowNumber, 
               id, 
               customerno, 
               customername, 
               customersurname, 
               customertitle, 
               customerunitlist, 
               customertotallist 
        FROM   (SELECT m.id, 
                       m.customerno, 
                       m.customername, 
                       m.customersurname, 
                       m.customertitle, 
                       (SELECT Count(f.id) 
                        FROM   invoices f 
                        WHERE  f.paid = 0 
                               AND f.custumercancel = 0 
                               AND f.customerid = m.id)            AS 
                       customerUnitList, 
                       Isnull((SELECT Sum(f.total) AS InvoiceNo 
                               FROM   invoices f 
                               WHERE  f.paid = 0 
                                      AND f.custumercancel = 0 
                                      AND f.customerid = m.id), 0) AS 
                       customerTotalList 
                FROM   customers m) flist 
        WHERE  customertotallist > 0) x 
WHERE  rownumber BETWEEN 1 AND 100
```

you are supposed to apply row number filter for paging, only after applying all your custom filters.

Comment: Oh, now I see the point. Ive spent about 3-4 hours to fix this issue ^^

Answer (score 0):

Using `WHERE` *outside* of the row_number() creating query means that some rows might be filtered by that. I bet that if you comment out the line before the last (`customerTotalList>0`) you will always get 100 rows.

If you want 100, you can just use

`select top 100..........order by RowNumber asc`

Answer (score 0):

Which version of MS SQL Server do you have? This old approach was usable before to MS SQL Server 2012, from 2012 and up you have 0FFSET FETCH for pagination scenario.

Comment: This is MS SQL 2012, since I am quite new I am just practising with currently set up one. Later on hopefully I will upgrade queries for newer versions. I'll keep that in mind for further work, thank you :)